# Formatted DateTime value is not getting inserted - sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to execute this query from my code

```
using (SqlCommand usageMapCmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    usageMapCmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
    usageMapCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    usageMapCmd.CommandText = "INSERT [dbo].[Analytics_DeviceLog] ([IPAddress], [OS], [OSVersionMajor], [OSVersionMinor], [City], [Country], [CountryCode], [Region], [RegionCode], [PostalCode], [TimeZone], [Browser], [BrowserVersionMajor], [BrowserVersionMinor], [Device], [Model], [Platform], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Languages], [UserGuid], [LoginTimeUtc], [LocationAccuracy]) VALUES (N'119.15.106.186', N'Windows 10', NULL, NULL, N'Canberra', N'Australia', N'AU', N'Australian Capital Territory', N'ACT', N'2600', N'Australia/Sydney', N'@Browser', 60, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), N'@Device', N'', N'WinNT', CAST(-35.305000 AS Decimal(9, 6)), CAST(149.141200 AS Decimal(9, 6)), N'en-US,en;q=0.8,vi;q=0.6', N'99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999', CAST(N'@LoginTimeUtc' AS DateTime), N'Low')";
    usageMapCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Browser", (string)browsers[rndBrowsers.Next(browsers.Count)]);
    usageMapCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device", (string)devices[rndDevices.Next(devices.Count)]);
    usageMapCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginTimeUtc", loginTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    usageMapCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The problem i'm having is no matter what format of `@LoginTimeUtc` I entered I will got an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

The strange thing is when I executed the query manually from SQL Server Management Studio e.g. `2017-08-21 05:45:52.830` this will work fine so problems is not from my db I think.

I have tried. `DateTime.Parse(loginTimeUtc)` but no luck. I even tried to replace `loginTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")` with simple `DateTime.Now` but it's not working as well. Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Using SQL Server Profiler and this is what I got:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Analytics_DeviceLog] ([IPAddress], [OS], [OSVersionMajor], [OSVersionMinor], [City], [Country], [CountryCode], [Region], [RegionCode], [PostalCode], [TimeZone], [Browser], [BrowserVersionMajor], [BrowserVersionMinor], [Device], [Model], [Platform], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Languages], [UserGuid], [LoginTimeUtc], [LocationAccuracy]) VALUES (N''119.15.106.186'', N''Windows 10'', NULL, NULL, N''Canberra'', N''Australia'', N''AU'', N''Australian Capital Territory'', N''ACT'', N''2600'', N''Australia/Sydney'', N''@Browser'', 60, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), N''@Device'', N'''', N''WinNT'', CAST(-35.305000 AS Decimal(9, 6)), CAST(149.141200 AS Decimal(9, 6)), N''en-US,en;q=0.8,vi;q=0.6'', N''99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999'', N''@LoginTimeUtc'', N''Low'')',N'@Browser nvarchar(6),@Device nvarchar(17),@LoginTimeUtc datetime',@Browser=N'Chrome',@Device=N'Samsung Galaxy S4',@LoginTimeUtc='2009-02-19 21:56:00'
```

Comment: what is the type of `loginTimeUtc` in your code?

Comment: @un-lucky it is type DateTime

Comment: You can insert the date parameter as DateTime type. You dont need to convert it to a string

Comment: You are converting from object C# `System.DateTime` to String, then in your update, you convert back to SQL DateTime again, just remove your cast, and remove your `ToString()`

Comment: @JackyI have removed CAST AS DateTime and ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") but still got the same error

Comment: Hmm i normally use a "2017/11/20" format Which works fine.

Comment: @Harry I have also tried 2017/11/20" before but it wouldn't work as well. So fustating, none of the date format I have tried will work

Comment: I recently added date parameters to a sql query with c# datetimes as follows:
`fromDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead for converting DateTime to a formatted string, cast them back as DateTime for database and store, You can directly pass the DateTime object like this by using `Parameters.Add` by specifying `SqlDbType` :

```
 usageMapCmd.CommandText = "INSERT [dbo].[Analytics_DeviceLog] ([LoginTimeUtc]) VALUES (@LoginTimeUtc)";
 usageMapCmd.Parameters.Add("@LoginTimeUtc",SqlDbType.DateTime).value = loginTimeUtc;
```

Comment: I still have "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error with this

Comment: @sunsun I'd get out sql profiler and check the query that is actually being executed

Comment: @Mick this is what I got from Sql Profiler: post edited

Comment: What is the type of column `LoginTimeUtc` in the table

Comment: @un-lucky it is type datetime in the table

Comment: So the column `LoginTimeUtc` is DateTime and variable `loginTimeUtc` is also DateTime. Then I don't see any chances for such error, please do a recheck with your code and debug

Comment: You haven't implemented as indicated in this answer you still have quotes around the LoginTimeUtc parameter in the command text, it should read .... N''99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999'', @LoginTimeUtc, N''Low'')'... not ...N''99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999'', N''@LoginTimeUtc'', N''Low'')'

Comment: @Mick oops didn't notice that I haven't removed teh N'' around LoginTimeUtc. Now it is working. Thanks for your help

Comment: @un-lucky it is working for me now. Thanks for your help :) Appreciate it

Comment: @sunsun you should mark his answer as "the answer" i.e click the tick

Answer (score 0):

I think Un-Lucky's answer is the correct solution however you could probably get your code to work by changing the command text to...

```
usageMapCmd.CommandText = "INSERT [dbo].[Analytics_DeviceLog] ([IPAddress], [OS], [OSVersionMajor], [OSVersionMinor], [City], [Country], [CountryCode], [Region], [RegionCode], [PostalCode], [TimeZone], [Browser], [BrowserVersionMajor], [BrowserVersionMinor], [Device], [Model], [Platform], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Languages], [UserGuid], [LoginTimeUtc], [LocationAccuracy]) VALUES (N'119.15.106.186', N'Windows 10', NULL, NULL, N'Canberra', N'Australia', N'AU', N'Australian Capital Territory', N'ACT', N'2600', N'Australia/Sydney', N'@Browser', 60, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), N'@Device', N'', N'WinNT', CAST(-35.305000 AS Decimal(9, 6)), CAST(149.141200 AS Decimal(9, 6)), N'en-US,en;q=0.8,vi;q=0.6', N'99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999', CAST(@LoginTimeUtc AS DateTime), N'Low')";
```

i.e. change

```
CAST(N'@LoginTimeUtc' AS DateTime)
```

to

```
CAST(@LoginTimeUtc AS DateTime),
```

Your code is literally trying to convert the string "@LoginTimeUtc" instead of the parameter you are passing

**EDIT:** OK whilst creating an example to convince CodingYoshi, I discovered the other issue with the above code is the date formatter used which should be "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" not "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".  Anyhow, I've tested the following....

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=mytstDB;Integrated Security=True;pooling=true;Min Pool Size=5; Max Pool Size=10");
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE CreatedDate <= CAST(N'@LoginTimeUtc' AS DateTime)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginTimeUtc", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr.Read();
}
```

Which produces the following SQL in Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE CreatedDate <= CAST(N''@LoginTimeUtc'' AS DateTime)',N'@LoginTimeUtc nvarchar(19)',@LoginTimeUtc=N'2017-11-20 04:46:39'
```

which fails with a similar error as above.  Whilst, the following sql works..

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE CreatedDate <= CAST(@LoginTimeUtc AS DateTime)',N'@LoginTimeUtc nvarchar(19)',@LoginTimeUtc=N'2017-11-20 04:46:39'
```

Which can be reproduced by changing the above code to...

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=29150930_sonic_dev_next;Integrated Security=True;pooling=true;Min Pool Size=5; Max Pool Size=10");
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE CreatedDate <= CAST(@LoginTimeUtc AS DateTime)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginTimeUtc", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr.Read();
}
```

Comment: *Your code is literally trying to convert the string "@LoginTimeUtc"*: I dont think so. It will take the date on the application side and insert it between the single quotes.

Comment: @CodingYoshi the command text is unaffected... it does not substitute in a string literal for the date

Answer (score 0):

I saw you use `loginTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")`, change it to `loginTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

Take note that MM gives you 2 digits month while mm gives you 2 digits minutes.

To read more about custom DateTime format, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)